# Android Biometric Auth without BiometricDialog

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible to do a biometric authentication without the **BiometricDialog**?

I mean it seems to be done by some apps (**Revolut** and other financial apps).

Right now I'm using this library: https://github.com/pwittchen/RxBiometric
to handle the dialog and preconditions but I'm open to drop it.

My idea is to have a screen with an icon/label on the middle and to wait until the user touches the sensor, without any dialog.

All I can find around the web is using BiometricDialog.

P.S. using kotlin but I'm open to java solutions as well

Comment: If you're OK with only using fingerprint authentication (no face, iris, etc), then you can use the old `FingerprintManager` API. It doesn't have provide any UI of its own, so you can design the UI anyway you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Micheal suggested in the comment, the old `FingerprintManager` did the trick. It's deprecated but seems to work just fine.